# Hides UINavigationController's UIToolbar when pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I've two view controller `A` and `B`.

`A` contains a table view and when the user taps on a row, `B` is pushed.

`B` has a `UIToolbar` `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;` and the problem is when I pop from `B` to `A`: the toolbar remains even on `A` and I have no idea how to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you does not hide toolBar when you pop from `B` to `A` viewController.
Use/write following code in `B` viewController

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - viewWillDisappear Methods

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];    
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```

So, your toolBar hide whenever you pop from `B` to `A` viewController.
You Also should try with another option, use same code on `viewWillAppear` method of `A` viewController.